# The "Close" button isn't working on my paragraph element. What is wrong?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-5, close-button

I have a set of announcements on my website embedded inside

tags. I would like to give the users the ability to close these announcements and get on with their life. The following is an account of what I have done.

The following didn't close (hide) the paragraph element. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Bootstrap Version 5.1.3 and JQuery.

```js
function closeNote(button) {
  var note = button.parentNode;
  note.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.note {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 30px;
  /* Add space for the button */
}

.note .close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.note .close-button i {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.note .close-button:hover i {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="note notesbonus">
  <i class="bi bi-patch-plus-fill"></i> Note 1
  <button class="close-button" onclick="closeNote(this)">
      <i class="bi bi-x"></i>x
  </button>
</p>

<p class="note otherclass"> <i class="bi bi-patch-plus-fill"></i> Note 2 <button class="close-button" onclick="closeNote(this)">
      <i class="bi bi-x"></i>x
  </button>
</p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your script seems to work fine in the demo above. Please revise to show the problem.

Comment: But I can't style it the way I have done with the "notes" class, can I?

Comment: You can style the Bootstrap Alerts to look exactly like your example. And  it does not require any custom css or JavaScript.  See [demo Alert notes](https://jsfiddle.net/rhkc08b6/show)

Comment: @Yogi thank you very much indeed. I got my answer. Now what should I do to close the question? LOL (noob question)